# Rotate lines in a text file with n steps

Tags: linux, unix, command-line, command

I have a text file with thousands of lines and I need to rotate the lines . Here is an example:

`myfile.txt`:

```
line1
line2
line3
line4
line5
line6
line7
```

I would like to rotate the lines with `n` steps. For example, if `n = 2`. line1 moves to line3, line2 moves to line4, line3 moves to line 5, ... line6 moves to line1, line7 move to line2. So the output should be:

```
line6
line7
line1
line2
line3
line4
line5
```

Maybe I could use Python and read the file, and rotate the list, and save to another file. I wonder if there is already a command line utility for this purpose? it should take the filename and `n` as arguments and outputs the rotated lines to a new file.

I appreciate your help.

Comment: Do you really want line 2 to show up twice in the result?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`head`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/head.1.html) and [`tail`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tail.1.html), plus some simple [bash arithmetic expansion](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/arithexp.html). You also need either [`tac`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tac.1.html) or [`wc`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/wc.1.html):

First, create a minimum reproducible example for the input file. Set `n` - the number of lines from the end of the file to rotate to the beginning:

```
n = 2
perl -le 'print "line$_" for 1..7' > in_file
cat in_file
```

Prints:

```
line1
line2
line3
line4
line5
line6
line7
```

**Method 1: Rotate with `tail` and `head`, plus `wc`.**

This is slightly less complex than method 2, and uses `wc -l ... - $n` to compute the number of lines for the `head` to print. I prefer this method because the programmer's intentions are more clear here. It is also faster, see benchmarks below.

```
( tail -n $n in_file ; head -n $(( $( wc -l <in_file ) - $n )) in_file ) > out_file
```

Prints:

```
line6
line7
line1
line2
line3
line4
line5
```

**Method 2: Rotate with `tail` and `head`, plus `tac`.**

Here,
`tac` : write the lines in reverse order into STDOUT,
`tail -n +3` : write the above lines in reverse order starting from line 3 **from the end of the original file** (lines 1-2 are thus not written),
`tac` : use `tac` a total of twice, to reverse the reverse order of lines, in order to write the lines in the original order.

```
( tail -n $n in_file ; tac in_file | tail -n +$(( $n+1 )) | tac ) > out_file
```

**Benchmarks:**

Method 1 using `wc` is substantially faster that method 2 using `tac` twice:

```
perl -le 'print "line$_" for 1..1e7' > in_file
n=2
```

```
for i in `seq 1 10` ; do
    ( time ( tail -n $n in_file ; head -n $(( $( wc -l <in_file ) - $n )) in_file ) > out_file ) 2>&1 | grep real
done
```

Prints:

```
real    0m0.539s
real    0m0.538s
real    0m0.545s
real    0m0.566s
real    0m0.540s
real    0m0.532s
real    0m0.561s
real    0m0.534s
real    0m0.530s
real    0m0.520s
```

```
for i in `seq 1 10` ; do
    ( time ( tail -n $n in_file ; tac in_file | tail -n +$(( $n+1 )) | tac ) > out_file ) 2>&1 | grep real
done
```

Prints:

```
real    0m0.855s
real    0m0.884s
real    0m0.916s
real    0m0.829s
real    0m0.838s
real    0m0.873s
real    0m0.877s
real    0m0.862s
real    0m0.835s
real    0m0.867s
```

I ran this using MacBook Pro with macOS v.10.14.6, running:

```
bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin18)
```

Answer (score 0):

a bit verbose with awk, but..

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
  step=(!step)?2:step
}
{
  a[FNR+step]=$0
  nr=FNR
}
END {
  for(i=nr+1; i in a;i++)
    a[(i%step)+1]=a[i]
  for(i=1; i<=nr ;i++)
          print a[i]
}
```

```sh
$ awk -f tst.awk file
line6
line7
line1
line2
line3
line4
line5
```

```sh
$ awk -v step=4 -f tst.awk file
line4
line5
line6
line7
line1
line2
line3
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a method using `tee`, the job control commands `wait` and `&`, and `bash` process substitution, that unlike the answers so far, works with pipes and redirects, so the filename only needs to be mentioned once, or a stream can be used instead:

```
N=2
tee >(tail -n $N &) \
    >(wait && head -n -$N) > /dev/null < myfile.txt
```

Or, with a stream instead of a filename:

```
N=2
seq -f 'line%g' 7 | 
tee >(tail -n $N &) \
    >(wait && head -n -$N) > /dev/null
```

Output of either:

```
line6
line7
line1
line2
line3
line4
line5
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do this with the shell commands [`head`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/head) and [`tail`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tail). If you wanted to "rotate" a file of length N 2 times, you'd print the last N-2 lines of the file and then the first 2 lines.

The example below rotates a file called "rotate" with 5 lines 2 "times".

```sh
tail --lines 3 rotate
head --lines 2 rotate
```

or as a one-liner `tail --lines 3 rotate; head --lines 2 rotate`

Comment: Have you tried that? it doesn't give the expected output. What are those hardcoded values `3` and `2` ?

Comment: Weird, it gives me the expected output. What output did you receive? I wanted the first 2 lines, of a file with 5 lines. So i printed the last 3 lines (5 - 2) and then the first 2.